# Creating a custom rally list from source using app-catalog on github

Tags: rally, appsdk2, code-rally

I am trying to use the [Rally App Catalog](https://github.com/RallyApps/app-catalog) and the [custom list app](https://github.com/RallyApps/app-catalog/tree/master/src/apps/customlist)

I would like to add an additional selector (item type) and rename some of the headers on the fly. First I just want the sample to run. As it currently stands, it looks broken to me.

When I use the [rally-app-builder](https://github.com/RallyApps/rally-app-builder) build function and then paste the result app.html into a custom app I get a blank page with working app settings.

Here the uncompressed version from my initial attempt.

```html
<script src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/sdk-debug.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Custom List</title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/2.1/sdk.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    Rally.onReady(function() {
      (function() {
        var Ext = window.Ext4 || window.Ext;

        var getHiddenFieldConfig = function(name) {
          return {
            name: name,
            xtype: 'rallytextfield',
            hidden: true,
            handlesEvents: {
              typeselected: function(type) {
                this.setValue(null);
              }
            }
          };
        };

        Ext.define('Rally.apps.customlist.Settings', {
          singleton: true,
          requires: [
            'Rally.ui.combobox.FieldComboBox',
            'Rally.ui.combobox.ComboBox',
            'Rally.ui.CheckboxField'
          ],

          getFields: function(app) {
            this.app = app;
            return [{
                name: 'type',
                xtype: 'rallycombobox',
                allowBlank: false,
                autoSelect: false,
                shouldRespondToScopeChange: true,
                context: this.app.getContext(),
                initialValue: 'HierarchicalRequirement',
                storeConfig: {
                  model: Ext.identityFn('TypeDefinition'),
                  sorters: [{
                    property: 'DisplayName'
                  }],
                  fetch: ['DisplayName', 'ElementName', 'TypePath', 'Parent', 'UserListable'],
                  filters: [{
                    property: 'UserListable',
                    value: true
                  }],
                  autoLoad: false,
                  remoteSort: false,
                  remoteFilter: true
                },
                displayField: 'DisplayName',
                valueField: 'TypePath',
                listeners: {
                  select: function(combo) {
                    this.app.clearFiltersAndSharedViews();
                    combo.fireEvent('typeselected', combo.getRecord().get('TypePath'), combo.context);
                  },
                  scope: this
                },
                bubbleEvents: ['typeselected'],
                readyEvent: 'ready',
                handlesEvents: {
                  projectscopechanged: function(context) {
                    this.refreshWithNewContext(context);
                  }
                }
              }, {
                type: 'query'
              }, {
                name: 'showControls',
                xtype: 'rallycheckboxfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Show Control Bar'
              },
              getHiddenFieldConfig('columnNames'),
              getHiddenFieldConfig('order')
            ];
          }
        });
      })();
      (function() {
        var Ext = window.Ext4 || window.Ext;

        Ext.define('Rally.apps.customlist.CustomListApp', {
          extend: 'Rally.app.GridBoardApp',
          requires: [
            'Deft.Promise',
            'Rally.apps.customlist.Settings',
            'Rally.data.BulkRecordUpdater',
            'Rally.data.ModelTypes',
            'Rally.data.PreferenceManager',
            'Rally.data.util.Sorter',
            'Rally.data.wsapi.Filter',
            'Rally.ui.gridboard.plugin.GridBoardInlineFilterControl',
            'Rally.ui.gridboard.plugin.GridBoardSharedViewControl',
            'Rally.ui.notify.Notifier',
            'Rally.util.String'
          ],

          disallowedAddNewTypes: ['user', 'userprofile', 'useriterationcapacity', 'testcaseresult', 'task', 'scmrepository', 'project', 'changeset', 'change', 'builddefinition', 'build', 'program'],
          orderedAllowedPageSizes: [10, 25, 50, 100, 200],
          readOnlyGridTypes: ['build', 'change', 'changeset'],
          statePrefix: 'customlist',
          allowExpansionStateToBeSaved: false,
          isEditable: true,

          config: {
            defaultSettings: {
              showControls: true
            }
          },

          initComponent: function() {
            this.appName = 'CustomList-' + this.getAppId();
            this.callParent(arguments);
          },

          getSettingsFields: function() {
            return Rally.apps.customlist.Settings.getFields(this);
          },

          loadModelNames: function() {
            this.modelNames = _.compact([this._getTypeSetting()]);
            this._setColumnNames(this._getColumnNamesSetting());
            return Deft.Promise.when(this.modelNames);
          },

          addGridBoard: function() {
            this.callParent(arguments);

            if (!this.getSetting('showControls')) {
              this.gridboard.getHeader().hide();
            }
          },

          loadGridBoard: function() {
            if (_.isEmpty(this.modelNames)) {
              Ext.defer(function() {
                this.fireEvent('settingsneeded', this);
                this.publishComponentReady();
              }, 1, this);
            } else {
              this.enableAddNew = this._shouldEnableAddNew();
              this.enableRanking = this._shouldEnableRanking();
              this.callParent(arguments);
            }
          },

          getGridConfig: function() {
            var config = _.merge(this.callParent(arguments), {
              allColumnsStateful: true,
              enableEditing: !_.contains(this.readOnlyGridTypes, this._getTypeSetting().toLowerCase()),
              listeners: {
                beforestaterestore: this._onBeforeGridStateRestore,
                beforestatesave: this._onBeforeGridStateSave,
                scope: this
              },
              pagingToolbarCfg: {
                hidden: !this.getSetting('showControls'),
                pageSizes: this.orderedAllowedPageSizes
              }
            });

            var invalidQueryFilters = Rally.util.Filter.findInvalidSubFilters(this._getQueryFilter(), this.models);
            if (invalidQueryFilters.length) {
              config.store.on('beforeload', function(store) {
                Ext.defer(function() {
                  store.fireEvent('load', store, store.getRootNode(), [], true);
                }, 1);
                return false;
              });
              this._showInvalidQueryMessage(config, _.map(invalidQueryFilters, function(filter) {
                return 'Could not find the attribute "' + filter.property.split('.')[0] + '" on type "' + this.models[0].displayName + '" in the query segment "' + filter.toString() + '"';
              }, this));
            }

            return config;
          },

          getColumnCfgs: function() {
            return _.union(this.callParent(arguments), _.isEmpty(this.columnNames) && this.enableRanking ? ['DragAndDropRank'] : []);
          },

          getFilterControlConfig: function() {
            return _.merge(this.callParent(arguments), {
              listeners: {
                beforestaterestore: {
                  fn: this._onBeforeFilterButtonStateRestore,
                  scope: this
                }
              }
            });
          },

          getGridBoardCustomFilterControlConfig: function() {
            var context = this.getContext();
            var isArtifactModel = this.models[0].isArtifact();
            var blackListFields = isArtifactModel ? ['ModelType', 'PortfolioItemType'] : ['ArtifactSearch', 'ModelType'];
            var whiteListFields = isArtifactModel ? ['Milestones', 'Tags'] : [];

            if (this.models[0].isProject()) {
              blackListFields.push('SchemaVersion');
            } else if (this.models[0].isRelease()) {
              blackListFields.push('ChildrenPlannedVelocity', 'Version');
            }

            var config = {
              ptype: 'rallygridboardinlinefiltercontrol',
              inlineFilterButtonConfig: {
                stateful: true,
                stateId: context.getScopedStateId('custom-list-inline-filter'),
                legacyStateIds: [
                  this.getScopedStateId('owner-filter'),
                  this.getScopedStateId('custom-filter-button')
                ],
                filterChildren: true,
                inlineFilterPanelConfig: {
                  quickFilterPanelConfig: {
                    defaultFields: isArtifactModel ? ['ArtifactSearch', 'Owner'] : [],
                    addQuickFilterConfig: {
                      blackListFields: blackListFields,
                      whiteListFields: whiteListFields
                    }
                  },
                  advancedFilterPanelConfig: {
                    advancedFilterRowsConfig: {
                      propertyFieldConfig: {
                        blackListFields: blackListFields,
                        whiteListFields: whiteListFields
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            };

            if (isArtifactModel) {
              config.inlineFilterButtonConfig.modelNames = this.modelNames;
            } else {
              config.inlineFilterButtonConfig.model = this.models[0];
            }

            return config;
          },

          getSharedViewConfig: function() {
            var context = this.getContext();
            return {
              ptype: 'rallygridboardsharedviewcontrol',
              sharedViewConfig: {
                stateful: true,
                stateId: context.getScopedStateId('custom-list-shared-view'),
                enableUrlSharing: this.isFullPageApp !== false
              }
            };
          },

          getGridBoardConfig: function() {
            var config = this.callParent(arguments);
            return _.merge(config, {
              listeners: {
                viewchange: function() {
                  this.loadGridBoard();
                },
                filterchange: function() {
                  this.gridboard.getGridOrBoard().noDataPrimaryText = undefined;
                  this.gridboard.getGridOrBoard().noDataSecondaryText = undefined;
                },
                scope: this
              }
            });
          },

          onTreeGridReady: function(grid) {
            if (grid.store.getTotalCount() > 10) {
              this.gridboard.down('#pagingToolbar').show();
            }

            this.callParent(arguments);
          },

          getGridStoreConfig: function() {
            var sorters = this._getValidSorters(Rally.data.util.Sorter.sorters(this.getSetting('order')));

            if (_.isEmpty(sorters)) {
              var rankField = this.getContext().getWorkspace().WorkspaceConfiguration.DragDropRankingEnabled ? 'DragAndDropRank' : 'Rank';
              var defaultSort = Rally.data.ModelTypes.areArtifacts(this.modelNames) ? rankField : Rally.data.util.Sorter.getDefaultSort(this.modelNames[0]);

              sorters = Rally.data.util.Sorter.sorters(defaultSort);
            }

            return {
              listeners: {
                warning: {
                  fn: this._onGridStoreWarning,
                  scope: this
                }
              },
              pageSize: 10,
              sorters: sorters
            };
          },

          getAddNewConfig: function() {
            var config = {
              minWidth: 700,
              openEditorAfterAddFailure: false,
              margin: 0
            };

            if (!this.getContext().isFeatureEnabled('F6971_REACT_DASHBOARD_PANELS')) {
              config.disableAddButton = this.appContainer.slug === 'incompletestories';
            }

            return _.merge(this.callParent(arguments), config);
          },

          getFieldPickerConfig: function() {
            return _.merge(this.callParent(arguments), {
              buttonConfig: {
                disabled: !this._userHasPermissionsToEditPanelSettings()
              },
              gridAlwaysSelectedValues: function() {
                return [];
              },
              gridFieldBlackList: this._getTypeSetting().toLowerCase() === 'task' ? ['Rank'] : []
            });
          },

          getPermanentFilters: function() {
            return this._getQueryFilter().concat(this._getTimeboxScopeFilter()).concat(this._getProjectFilter());
          },

          onTimeboxScopeChange: function() {
            this.callParent(arguments);
            this.loadGridBoard();
          },

          clearFiltersAndSharedViews: function() {
            var context = this.getContext();
            if (this.gridboard) {
              this.gridboard.down('rallyinlinefilterpanel').clear();
              this.gridboard.down('rallysharedviewcombobox').reset();
            }

            Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
              model: Ext.identityFn('preference'),
              autoLoad: true,
              filters: [{
                property: 'AppId',
                value: context.getAppId()
              }, {
                property: 'Type',
                value: 'View'
              }, {
                property: 'Workspace',
                value: context.getWorkspace()._ref
              }],
              context: context.getDataContext(),
              listeners: {
                load: function(store, records) {
                  if (!_.isEmpty(records)) {
                    var batchStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.batch.Store', {
                      requester: this,
                      data: records
                    });
                    batchStore.removeAll();
                    batchStore.sync();
                  }
                  store.destroyStore();
                },
                scope: this
              }
            });
          },

          _getTypeSetting: function() {
            return this.getSetting('type') || this.getSetting('url');
          },

          _getColumnNamesSetting: function() {
            return this.getSetting('columnNames') ||
              (this.getSetting('fetch') || '').split(',');
          },

          _getQueryFilter: function() {
            var query = new Ext.Template(this.getSetting('query')).apply({
              projectName: this.getContext().getProject().Name,
              projectOid: this.getContext().getProject().ObjectID,
              user: this.getContext().getUser()._ref
            });
            if (query) {
              try {
                return [Rally.data.wsapi.Filter.fromQueryString(query)];
              } catch (e) {
                Rally.ui.notify.Notifier.showError({
                  message: e.message
                });
              }
            }
            return [];
          },

          _getProjectFilter: function() {
            return this.modelNames[0].toLowerCase() === 'milestone' ? [
              Rally.data.wsapi.Filter.or([{
                property: 'Projects',
                operator: 'contains',
                value: this.getContext().getProjectRef()
              }, {
                property: 'TargetProject',
                operator: '=',
                value: null
              }])
            ] : [];
          },

          _getTimeboxScopeFilter: function() {
            var timeboxScope = this.getContext().getTimeboxScope();
            var hasTimeboxField = timeboxScope && _.any(this.models, timeboxScope.isApplicable, timeboxScope);
            return hasTimeboxField ? [timeboxScope.getQueryFilter()] : [];
          },

          _shouldEnableAddNew: function() {
            return !_.contains(this.disallowedAddNewTypes, this._getTypeSetting().toLowerCase());
          },

          _shouldEnableRanking: function() {
            return this._getTypeSetting().toLowerCase() !== 'task';
          },

          _setColumnNames: function(columnNames) {
            this.columnNames = _.compact(_.isString(columnNames) ? columnNames.split(',') : columnNames);
          },

          _onBeforeFilterButtonStateRestore: function(filterButton, state) {
            if (state && state.filters && state.filters.length) {
              var stateFilters = _.map(state.filters, function(filterStr) {
                return Rally.data.wsapi.Filter.fromQueryString(filterStr);
              });
              var validFilters = Rally.util.Filter.removeNonapplicableTypeSpecificFilters(stateFilters, this.models);
              state.filters = _.invoke(validFilters, 'toString');
            }
          },

          _hasViewSelected: function() {
            var sharedViewConfig = this.getSharedViewConfig().sharedViewConfig;
            if (sharedViewConfig && sharedViewConfig.stateId) {
              var value = (Ext.state.Manager.get(sharedViewConfig.stateId) || {}).value;

              return !_.isEmpty(value);
            }
            return false;
          },

          _onBeforeGridStateRestore: function(grid, state) {
            if (!state) {
              return;
            }

            if (state.columns) {
              var appScopedColumnNames = this._getValidUuids(grid, this.getColumnCfgs());
              var userScopedColumnNames = this._getValidUuids(grid, state.columns);

              if (this._hasViewSelected()) {
                state.columns = userScopedColumnNames;
              } else {

                // Get the columns that are present in the app scope and not in the user scope
                var differingColumns = _.difference(appScopedColumnNames, userScopedColumnNames);

                // If there are columns in the app scope that are not in the
                // user scope, append them to the user scope to preserve
                // user scope column order
                if (differingColumns.length > 0) {
                  state.columns = state.columns.concat(differingColumns);
                }

                // Filter out any columns that are in the user scope that are not in the
                // app scope
                state.columns = _.filter(state.columns, function(column) {
                  return _.contains(appScopedColumnNames, _.isObject(column) ? column.dataIndex : column);
                }, this);
              }
            }

            if (state.sorters) {
              state.sorters = this._getValidSorters(state.sorters);
              if (_.isEmpty(state.sorters)) {
                delete state.sorters;
              }
            }
          },

          _getValidUuids: function(grid, columns) {
            return _.reduce(columns, function(result, column) {
              var dataIndex = this._getColumnDataIndex(column);
              var field = this._getModelField(grid, dataIndex);

              if (field) {
                result.push(dataIndex);
              }

              return result;
            }, [], this);
          },

          _getModelField: function(grid, dataIndex) {
            return grid.getModels()[0].getField(dataIndex);
          },

          _getColumnDataIndex: function(column) {
            return _.isObject(column) ? column.dataIndex : column;
          },

          _onBeforeGridStateSave: function(grid, state) {
            var newColumnNames = this._getColumnNamesFromState(state);

            if (!_.isEmpty(newColumnNames)) {
              this._setColumnNames(newColumnNames);

              if (this._userHasPermissionsToEditPanelSettings()) {
                this.updateSettingsValues({
                  settings: {
                    columnNames: newColumnNames.join(',')
                  }
                });
              }
            }
          },

          _onGridStoreWarning: function(store, warnings, operation) {
            var couldNotParseWarnings = _.filter(warnings, function(warning) {
              return Rally.util.String.startsWith(warning, 'Could not parse ');
            });
            if (couldNotParseWarnings.length) {
              _.assign(operation.resultSet, {
                count: 0,
                records: [],
                total: 0,
                totalRecords: 0
              });
              this._showInvalidQueryMessage(this.gridboard.getGridOrBoard(), couldNotParseWarnings);
            }
          },

          _showInvalidQueryMessage: function(gridOrGridConfig, secondaryTextStrings) {
            gridOrGridConfig.noDataPrimaryText = 'Invalid Query';
            gridOrGridConfig.noDataSecondaryText = _.map(secondaryTextStrings, function(str) {
              return '<div>' + str + '</div>';
            }).join('');
          },

          _getValidSorters: function(sorters) {
            return _.filter(sorters, function(sorter) {
              return _.any(this.models, function(model) {
                var field = model.getField(sorter.property);
                return field && field.sortable;
              });
            }, this);
          },

          _userHasPermissionsToEditPanelSettings: function() {
            return this.isEditable;
          },

          _getColumnNamesFromState: function(state) {
            return _(state && state.columns).map(function(newColumn) {
              return _.isObject(newColumn) ? newColumn.dataIndex : newColumn;
            }).compact().value();
          }
        });
      })();


      Rally.launchApp('Rally.apps.customlist.CustomListApp', {
        name: "Custom List",
        parentRepos: ""
      });

    });
  </script>


</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got results by commenting out the following lines in getAddNewConfig:

```js
        getAddNewConfig: function () {
            var config = {
                minWidth: 700,
                openEditorAfterAddFailure: false,
                margin: 0
            };

            //if(!this.getContext().isFeatureEnabled('F6971_REACT_DASHBOARD_PANELS')) {
            //    config.disableAddButton = this.appContainer.slug === 'incompletestories';
            //}

            return _.merge(this.callParent(arguments), config);
        },
```

It seems that 'this.appContainer.slug' is undefined for me.

Comment: sorry for the wag- that was a known issue with that app.  there may be a couple other references to this.appContainer or this.owner to work around as well.  the app has since been fixed, but looks like it didn't quite make the cut for the 2.1 sdk release...

Comment: Is that why the filter gadgets are missing from the example vs the Rally supplied version?

Comment: I made a pull request with the updated app code here: https://github.com/RallyApps/app-catalog/pull/8

Maybe you can try pasting the updated contents of those two files into your app and see where that gets you?  It should be basically exactly the same as the in-product catalog version now...

Comment: I tried the code from the branch upgrade_custom_list_app and received "Error: success callback for Deferred transformed result of Deferred transformed result of Deferred transformed result of Deferred transformed result of Deferred threw: TypeError: Cannot read property 'slug' of undefined" in the chrome debugger.

Comment: Here is a gist https://gist.github.com/nbmorgan/48d7c0994a0846947b0b53e570b341d0 of my result

Comment: d'oh! i missed deleting that.  i re-pushed to that branch.  basically though if you just delete that if block on 317 that is exploding you should be good i think...

Answer (score 0):

Here's the final working CustomListApp.js generated from the comment stream in the answer above.  The main tweaks were deleting some old code checking a feature toggle and giving it a default type to display (defect in this case) in the defaultSettings block.

```
(function() {
    var Ext = window.Ext4 || window.Ext;

    Ext.define('Rally.apps.customlist.CustomListApp', {
        extend: 'Rally.app.GridBoardApp',
        requires: [
            'Deft.Promise',
            'Rally.apps.customlist.Settings',
            'Rally.data.BulkRecordUpdater',
            'Rally.data.ModelTypes',
            'Rally.data.PreferenceManager',
            'Rally.data.util.Sorter',
            'Rally.data.wsapi.Filter',
            'Rally.ui.gridboard.plugin.GridBoardInlineFilterControl',
            'Rally.ui.gridboard.plugin.GridBoardSharedViewControl',
            'Rally.ui.notify.Notifier',
            'Rally.util.String'
        ],

        disallowedAddNewTypes: ['user', 'userprofile', 'useriterationcapacity', 'testcaseresult', 'task', 'scmrepository', 'project', 'changeset', 'change', 'builddefinition', 'build', 'program'],
        orderedAllowedPageSizes: [10, 25, 50, 100, 200],
        readOnlyGridTypes: ['build', 'change', 'changeset'],
        statePrefix: 'customlist',
        allowExpansionStateToBeSaved: false,
        isEditable: true,

        config: {
            defaultSettings: {
                showControls: true,
                type: 'defect' //important to include a default type to display
            }
        },

        initComponent: function () {
            this.appName = 'CustomList-' + this.getAppId();
            if (this.defaultSettings.url) {
                Ext.apply(this.defaultSettings, { type: this.defaultSettings.url });
            }
            this.callParent(arguments);
        },

        getSettingsFields: function() {
            return Rally.apps.customlist.Settings.getFields(this);
        },

        loadModelNames: function () {
            this.modelNames = _.compact(this.getTypeSetting());
            this._setColumnNames(this._getColumnNamesSetting());
            return Deft.Promise.when(this.modelNames);
        },

        addGridBoard: function () {
            this.callParent(arguments);

            if (!this.getSetting('showControls')) {
                this.gridboard.getHeader().hide();
            }
        },

        loadGridBoard: function () {
            if (_.isEmpty(this.modelNames)) {
                Ext.defer(function () {
                    this.fireEvent('settingsneeded', this);
                    this.publishComponentReady();
                }, 1, this);
            } else {
                this.enableAddNew = this._shouldEnableAddNew();
                this.enableRanking = this._shouldEnableRanking();
                this.callParent(arguments);
            }
        },

        getGridConfig: function () {
            var config = _.merge(this.callParent(arguments), {
                allColumnsStateful: true,
                enableEditing: _.intersection(this.readOnlyGridTypes, this.getTypeSetting()).length === 0,
                listeners: {
                    beforestaterestore: this._onBeforeGridStateRestore,
                    beforestatesave: this._onBeforeGridStateSave,
                    scope: this
                },
                pagingToolbarCfg: {
                    hidden: !this.getSetting('showControls'),
                    pageSizes: this.orderedAllowedPageSizes
                }
            });

            var invalidQueryFilters = Rally.util.Filter.findInvalidSubFilters(this._getQueryFilter(), this.models);
            if (invalidQueryFilters.length) {
                config.store.on('beforeload', function (store) {
                    Ext.defer(function () {
                        store.fireEvent('load', store, store.getRootNode(), [], true);
                    }, 1);
                    return false;
                });
                this._showInvalidQueryMessage(config, _.map(invalidQueryFilters, function (filter) {
                    return 'Could not find the attribute "'+ filter.property.split('.')[0] +'" on type "'+ this.models[0].displayName +'" in the query segment "'+ filter.toString() + '"';
                }, this));
            }

            return config;
        },

        getColumnCfgs: function() {
            return _.union(this.callParent(arguments), _.isEmpty(this.columnNames) && this.enableRanking ? ['DragAndDropRank'] : []);
        },

        getFilterControlConfig: function () {
            return _.merge(this.callParent(arguments), {
                listeners: {
                    beforestaterestore: {
                        fn: this._onBeforeFilterButtonStateRestore,
                        scope: this
                    }
                }
            });
        },

        getGridBoardCustomFilterControlConfig: function() {
            var context = this.getContext();
            var isArtifactModel = this.models[0].isArtifact();
            var blackListFields = isArtifactModel ? ['ModelType', 'PortfolioItemType', 'LastResult'] : ['ArtifactSearch', 'ModelType'];
            var whiteListFields = isArtifactModel ? ['Milestones', 'Tags'] : [];

            if (this.models[0].isProject()) {
                blackListFields.push('SchemaVersion');
            } else if (this.models[0].isRelease()) {
                blackListFields.push('ChildrenPlannedVelocity', 'Version');
            }

            var config = {
                ptype: 'rallygridboardinlinefiltercontrol',
                inlineFilterButtonConfig: {
                    stateful: true,
                    stateId: context.getScopedStateId('custom-list-inline-filter'),
                    legacyStateIds: [
                        this.getScopedStateId('owner-filter'),
                        this.getScopedStateId('custom-filter-button')
                    ],
                    filterChildren: true,
                    inlineFilterPanelConfig: {
                        quickFilterPanelConfig: {
                            defaultFields: isArtifactModel ? ['ArtifactSearch', 'Owner'] : [],
                            addQuickFilterConfig: {
                                blackListFields: blackListFields,
                                whiteListFields: whiteListFields
                            }
                        },
                        advancedFilterPanelConfig: {
                            advancedFilterRowsConfig: {
                                propertyFieldConfig: {
                                    blackListFields: blackListFields,
                                    whiteListFields: whiteListFields
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            if (isArtifactModel) {
                config.inlineFilterButtonConfig.modelNames = this.modelNames;
            } else {
                config.inlineFilterButtonConfig.model = this.models[0];
            }

            return config;
        },

        getSharedViewConfig: function() {
            var context = this.getContext();
            return {
                ptype: 'rallygridboardsharedviewcontrol',
                sharedViewConfig: {
                    stateful: true,
                    stateId: context.getScopedStateId('custom-list-shared-view'),
                    enableUrlSharing: this.isFullPageApp !== false
                }
            };
        },

        getGridBoardConfig: function () {
            var config = this.callParent(arguments);
            return _.merge(config, {
                listeners: {
                    viewchange: function() {
                        this.loadGridBoard();
                    },
                    filterchange: function() {
                        this.gridboard.getGridOrBoard().noDataPrimaryText = undefined;
                        this.gridboard.getGridOrBoard().noDataSecondaryText = undefined;
                    },
                    scope: this
                }
            });
        },

        onTreeGridReady: function (grid) {
            if (grid.store.getTotalCount() > 10) {
                this.gridboard.down('#pagingToolbar').show();
            }

            this.callParent(arguments);
        },

        getGridStoreConfig: function () {
            var sorters = this._getValidSorters(Rally.data.util.Sorter.sorters(this.getSetting('order')));

            if (_.isEmpty(sorters)) {
                var rankField = this.getContext().getWorkspace().WorkspaceConfiguration.DragDropRankingEnabled ? 'DragAndDropRank' : 'Rank';
                var defaultSort = Rally.data.ModelTypes.areArtifacts(this.modelNames) ? rankField : Rally.data.util.Sorter.getDefaultSort(this.modelNames[0]);

                sorters = Rally.data.util.Sorter.sorters(defaultSort);
            }

            return {
                listeners: {
                    warning: {
                        fn: this._onGridStoreWarning,
                        scope: this
                    }
                },
                pageSize: 10,
                sorters: sorters
            };
        },

        getAddNewConfig: function () {
            var config = {
                minWidth: 700,
                openEditorAfterAddFailure: false,
                margin: 0
            };

            return _.merge(this.callParent(arguments), config);
        },

        getFieldPickerConfig: function () {
            return _.merge(this.callParent(arguments), {
                buttonConfig: {
                    disabled: !this._userHasPermissionsToEditPanelSettings()
                },
                gridAlwaysSelectedValues: function () { return []; },
                gridFieldBlackList: this._shouldEnableRanking() ? [] : ['Rank']
            });
        },

        getPermanentFilters: function () {
            return this._getQueryFilter().concat(this._getTimeboxScopeFilter()).concat(this._getProjectFilter());
        },

        onTimeboxScopeChange: function() {
            this.callParent(arguments);
            this.loadGridBoard();
        },

        clearFiltersAndSharedViews: function() {
            var context = this.getContext();
            if (this.gridboard) {
                this.gridboard.down('rallyinlinefilterpanel').clear();
                this.gridboard.down('rallysharedviewcombobox').reset();
            }

            Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
                model: Ext.identityFn('preference'),
                autoLoad: true,
                filters: [
                    {property: 'AppId', value: context.getAppId()},
                    {property: 'Type', value: 'View'},
                    {property: 'Workspace', value: context.getWorkspace()._ref}
                ],
                context: context.getDataContext(),
                listeners: {
                    load: function(store, records) {
                        if(!_.isEmpty(records)) {
                            var batchStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.batch.Store', {
                                requester: this,
                                data: records
                            });
                            batchStore.removeAll();
                            batchStore.sync();
                        }
                        store.destroyStore();
                    },
                    scope: this
                }
            });
        },

        getTypeSetting: function() {
            return (this.getSetting('type') || this.getSetting('url') || '').toLowerCase().split(',');
        },

        _getColumnNamesSetting: function() {
            return this.getSetting('columnNames') ||
              (this.getSetting('fetch') || '').split(',');
        },

        _getQueryFilter: function () {
            var query = new Ext.Template(this.getSetting('query')).apply({
                projectName: this.getContext().getProject().Name,
                projectOid: this.getContext().getProject().ObjectID,
                user: this.getContext().getUser()._ref
            });
            if (query) {
                try {
                    return [ Rally.data.wsapi.Filter.fromQueryString(query) ];
                } catch(e) {
                    Rally.ui.notify.Notifier.showError({ message: e.message });
                }
            }
            return [];
        },

        _getProjectFilter: function () {
            return this.modelNames[0].toLowerCase() === 'milestone' ? [
                Rally.data.wsapi.Filter.or([
                    { property: 'Projects', operator: 'contains', value: this.getContext().getProjectRef() },
                    { property: 'TargetProject', operator: '=', value: null }
                ])
            ] : [];
        },

        _getTimeboxScopeFilter: function () {
            var timeboxScope = this.getContext().getTimeboxScope();
            var hasTimeboxField = timeboxScope && _.any(this.models, timeboxScope.isApplicable, timeboxScope);
            return hasTimeboxField ? [ timeboxScope.getQueryFilter() ] : [];
        },

        _shouldEnableAddNew: function() {
            return _.intersection(this.disallowedAddNewTypes, this.getTypeSetting()).length === 0;
        },

        _shouldEnableRanking: function() {
            return !_.contains(this.getTypeSetting(), 'task');
        },

        _setColumnNames: function (columnNames) {
            this.columnNames = _.compact(_.isString(columnNames) ? columnNames.split(',') : columnNames);
        },

        _onBeforeFilterButtonStateRestore:  function (filterButton, state) {
            if (state && state.filters && state.filters.length) {
                var stateFilters = _.map(state.filters, function (filterStr) {
                    return Rally.data.wsapi.Filter.fromQueryString(filterStr);
                });
                var validFilters = Rally.util.Filter.removeNonapplicableTypeSpecificFilters(stateFilters, this.models);
                state.filters = _.invoke(validFilters, 'toString');
            }
        },

        _hasViewSelected: function() {
            var sharedViewConfig = this.getSharedViewConfig().sharedViewConfig;
            if (sharedViewConfig && sharedViewConfig.stateId) {
                var value = (Ext.state.Manager.get(sharedViewConfig.stateId) || {}).value;

                return !_.isEmpty(value);
            }
            return false;
        },

        _onBeforeGridStateRestore: function (grid, state) {
            if (!state) {
                return;
            }

            if (state.columns) {
                var appScopedColumnNames = this._getValidUuids(grid, this.getColumnCfgs());
                var userScopedColumnNames = this._getValidUuids(grid, state.columns);

                if (this._hasViewSelected()) {
                    state.columns = userScopedColumnNames;
                } else {

                    // Get the columns that are present in the app scope and not in the user scope
                    var differingColumns = _.difference(appScopedColumnNames, userScopedColumnNames);

                    // If there are columns in the app scope that are not in the
                    // user scope, append them to the user scope to preserve
                    // user scope column order
                    if (differingColumns.length > 0) {
                        state.columns = state.columns.concat(differingColumns);
                    }

                    // Filter out any columns that are in the user scope that are not in the
                    // app scope
                    state.columns = _.filter(state.columns, function (column) {
                        return _.contains(appScopedColumnNames, _.isObject(column) ? column.dataIndex : column);
                    }, this);
                }
            }

            if (state.sorters) {
                state.sorters = this._getValidSorters(state.sorters);
                if (_.isEmpty(state.sorters)) {
                    delete state.sorters;
                }
            }
        },

        _getValidUuids: function(grid, columns) {
            return _.reduce(columns, function(result, column) {
                var dataIndex =  this._getColumnDataIndex(column);
                var field = this._getModelField(grid, dataIndex);

                if (field) {
                    result.push(dataIndex);
                }

                return result;
            }, [], this);
        },

        _getModelField: function(grid, dataIndex) {
            return grid.getModels()[0].getField(dataIndex);
        },

        _getColumnDataIndex: function(column) {
            return _.isObject(column) ? column.dataIndex : column;
        },

        _onBeforeGridStateSave: function (grid, state) {
            var newColumnNames = this._getColumnNamesFromState(state);

            if (!_.isEmpty(newColumnNames)) {
                this._setColumnNames(newColumnNames);

                if (this._userHasPermissionsToEditPanelSettings()) {
                    this.updateSettingsValues({
                        settings: {
                            columnNames: newColumnNames.join(',')
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        },

        _onGridStoreWarning: function(store, warnings, operation) {
            var couldNotParseWarnings = _.filter(warnings, function(warning){
                return Rally.util.String.startsWith(warning, 'Could not parse ');
            });
            if(couldNotParseWarnings.length) {
                _.assign(operation.resultSet, {
                    count: 0,
                    records: [],
                    total: 0,
                    totalRecords: 0
                });
                this._showInvalidQueryMessage(this.gridboard.getGridOrBoard(), couldNotParseWarnings);
            }
        },

        _showInvalidQueryMessage: function(gridOrGridConfig, secondaryTextStrings) {
            gridOrGridConfig.noDataPrimaryText = 'Invalid Query';
            gridOrGridConfig.noDataSecondaryText = _.map(secondaryTextStrings, function(str){
                return '<div>' + str + '</div>';
            }).join('');
        },

        _getValidSorters: function (sorters) {
            return _.filter(sorters, function (sorter) {
                return _.any(this.models, function (model) {
                    var field = model.getField(sorter.property);
                    return field && field.sortable;
                });
            }, this);
        },

        _userHasPermissionsToEditPanelSettings: function () {
            return this.isEditable;
        },

        _getColumnNamesFromState: function (state) {
            return _(state && state.columns).map(function (newColumn) {
                return _.isObject(newColumn) ? newColumn.dataIndex : newColumn;
            }).compact().value();
        }
    });
})();
```